# How to create non-overlapping buffers around lines?

Tags: r, buffer, line, polygon

I would like to create non overlapping polygons that represent the area in which each line is the nearest to points within the area, up to a threshold distance (in this case 10m). Reproducible example plus sketch of what I'm thinking below.

```r
# question about buffer types
    library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.7.1, GDAL 2.4.2, PROJ 5.2.0
    library(stplanr)
    library(tmap)
    l1 = stplanr::osm_net_example[1, ]
    l = stplanr::osm_net_example[l1, ]
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes that they are planar
    lb = geo_projected(shp = l, fun = st_buffer, dist = 10)
    lb_flat = geo_projected(shp = l, fun = st_buffer, dist = 10, endCapStyle = "FLAT")
    plot(st_geometry(l))
    plot(st_geometry(lb), col = sf.colors(nrow(l), alpha = 0.5), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
    plot(st_geometry(l))
    plot(st_geometry(lb_flat), col = sf.colors(nrow(l), alpha = 0.5), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Here's the sketch (not my finest artistic piece of work!):

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this, but is what you're looking for as simple as calling `st_difference` on the shape?

Comment: I don't think so because the aim is for the resulting polygons to represent the halfway points between line pairs. `st_difference` would remove most of the pink polygon I think. If there were a way to make `st_difference` remove equal areas from line pairs that would help. I think the solution may involve `st_voronoi`

Comment: Yes, if the overlap space is divided by minimum distance to line segment then you're doing a sort of "voronoi" based on line segments instead of points. Might be fake-able by generating dense points on the lines, doing voronoi, unoining by line ID, clip to the buffer...

Comment: Ideas here I think solve it: https://github.com/ropensci/stplanr/issues/362#issuecomment-551722374

Answer (score 0):

There is a new QGis 3 plugin named "Buffer without overlaps" that do exactly this!